# Middle-click on speaker indicator to disable (mute) sound

Tags: sound, 18.04, mouse, gnome-shell

**Context:** I used a to-me-usefull feature of Ubuntu 16.04 that was to disable (and turn back on) sound at middle-click on top-left speaker indicator (in addition to volume increase/decrease when scrolling).

**Problem:** On my fresh Ubuntu 18.04 install, only the scrolling feature works.

**Question:** How to make that a middle click on the speaker icon (the second from left on attached picture) enable/disable sound (i.e (un)mute sound) on Ubuntu  18.04?

[image]

Comment: [Here](https://trello.com/c/6zZDZyBT) is a ticket from the ubuntu-desktop-1804-cycle Trello concerning this topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a GNOME shell extension called "[Toggle Mute on Middle Click](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1473/toggle-mute-on-middle-click/)". As the name suggests, this extension lets you toggle mute by middle-clicking the volume indicator.

Refer to this question-and-answer to learn more about GNOME extensions: [How do I install and manage GNOME Shell extensions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions)